# Restricting internet access of some client systems of LAN to a few websites using gateway

Tags: networking, iptables, ubuntu-12.04, internet, gateway

How to limit internet access of most systems in my LAN to a few websites and block all the other websites? Also want to bypass that restrictions for some systems. All systems have static IP address and also in wired LAN.

I have tried Dansguardian+squid in independent system, but as the users are able to change proxies in their web browsers it can't be implemented. While browsing on net I came to know that it can be done by using a gateway system(ubuntu) in between the router and LAN.

Equip the gateway system with two network cards, one for router and other for local LAN. Kindly help with how to configure gateway system and set rules in iptables to limit internet access of systems with IP address and bypass filtration for some IP addresses.

Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to resolve this. This [website](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/ubuntu-as-a-firewallgateway-router) helped me a lot. That was the scenario I had. Later configured iptables to restrict some client systems to few websites. I configured a ubuntu system as gateway between LAN and ADSL router. Then set rules in firewall (iptables) to restrict source systems (client) to some websites. This [website](http://kevinboone.net/linux_gateway.html) helped me in setting rule in iptables.

Sometimes this might help someone. I am happy to help if anyone have queries relating this.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a system like enidan firewall ([Endian free community version](http://www.endian.com/en/community/download)) as router to your outgoing network. Enable there just the ports you want directly to be reached outside (so e.q. 80 and 443 are blocked).

Then the user must use the proxy to get internet access.